# performance of a self join on oracle db

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle11g, query-optimization, self-join

I have this self join that is very slow on oracle DB. I have put indexes on all fields concerned. Does anybody have advice on how to increase performance?

```
select count(tNew.idtariffa)  CONT  
    from tariffe tAtt 
    join tariffe tNew on tAtt.idtariffa = tNew.idtariffa 
    where (tAtt.stato_attivo = 't') 
     and (tNew.stato_attivo = 'f') 
     and (tAtt.validity_date < tNew.validity_date) 
     and (tAtt.dataimport < tNew.dataimport) 
     and (tNew.validity_date < to_date('2017-6-26','YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

Comment: don't join, count from 1 table.

Comment: I m a little bit new bie I dont understand

Comment: look at Query Execution Plan

Comment: If you have just done a bulk load or bulk insert into the table, do perform gather stats on the table.

Comment: Is the "idtariffa " field Primary or Unique KEY?

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Here that includes DDL, data, query plan(s).

Answer (score 1):

Try  `PUSH_PRED` hint :

```
select /*+ NO_MERGE(tNew) PUSH_PRED(tNew) */
count(tNew.idtariffa)  CONT  
    from tariffe tAtt 
    join tariffe tNew on tAtt.idtariffa = tNew.idtariffa 
    where (tAtt.stato_attivo = 't') 
     and (tNew.stato_attivo = 'f') 
     and (tAtt.validity_date < tNew.validity_date) 
     and (tAtt.dataimport < tNew.dataimport) 
     and (tNew.validity_date < to_date('2017-6-26','YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

Comment: If I do "explain plan" the @mehmet-sahin   query and the ponder-stibbons query have exactly the same cost of mine query ...mmmmm...

Answer (score 1):

`Exists` version is worth of try:

```
select count(1) cont
  from tariffe n
  where stato_attivo = 'f'
    and validity_date < date '2017-06-26'
    and exists ( select null
                   from tariffe
                   where idtariffa = n.idtariffa
                     and stato_attivo = 't'
                     and validity_date < n.validity_date
                     and dataimport < n.dataimport )
```

Answer (score 1):

Performance tuning without details like data volumes, data skew, index defintions, explain plan, etc is just guessing.

So here are some more guesses :)

Your driving table should be `tariffe tNew` as that's the one you use to top the result set.

```
tNew.validity_date < to_date('2017-6-26','YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

Now, unless `tNew.stato_attivo = 'f'` is extremely selective you're going to be retrieving a large chunk of all the rows in the table (depending on how far back the records go) so a Full Table Scan would be the most efficient way of grabbing those records.

The join on `tariffe tAtt` is problematic because `idtariffa` is not a unique column. So the join is a set of `tNew` records against a set of `tAtt` records. These will be filtered in memory using the criteria in the WHERE clause.

> " I have put indexes on all fields concerned"

Single column indexes won't help here. You might get some joy from a compound index on all the pertinent columns:

```
tariffe (stato_attivo , validity_date, idtariffa, dataimport)
```

This would be worth building if you run this query very often.

Any other guesses? Subquery factoring to hit the main table once. Doing a Full Table Scan just once would speed things up if `tariffe` has a lot of columns.

```
with cte as ( 
       select stato_attivo , validity_date, idtariffa, dataimport
       from tariffe
       where validity_date < to_date('2017-6-26','YYYY-MM-DD'
   )
select count(tNew.idtariffa)  CONT  
from cte tNew 
    join cte tAtt on tAtt.idtariffa = tNew.idtariffa 
where (tAtt.stato_attivo = 't') 
and (tNew.stato_attivo = 'f') 
and (tAtt.validity_date < tNew.validity_date) 
and (tAtt.dataimport < tNew.dataimport)
```